# no views.py & models.py when I create django project in pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm

It's weird, I'm using PyCharm as IDE and Linux as a server to create a Django project. 
After running `startapp message` on PyCharm `Tools -> Run manage.py task`, I can see regular dictionary and files on server(as Terminal display shown). But I could not find them on PyCharm screen(as PyCharm display shown).
Why? Thank you guys, it's disturbed me for a long time...
[PyCharm display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o8nA.png)
[Terminal display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGSms.jpg)

Comment: It can take some time before PyCharm "updated" the directories. If I recall correctly you can "refresh" a directory, such that PyCharm looks for new/missing files.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"? Actually, I've thought about that, I looked tips, someone told me that in 'VCS' drop-list I could refresh it, but my drop-list is totally different from his list, OMG